# How should I change the views directory for vercel deployment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, vercel

I am trying to deploy an Express application with EJS template on vercel. After the deployment, it is showing the internal server error. This is what I am getting in the logs.
`Error: Failed to lookup view "home.ejs" in views directory "/var/task/views" at Function.render (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:597:17) at ServerResponse.render (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1039:7) at /var/task/app.js:16:9 at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) at next (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13) at Route.dispatch (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3) at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5) at /var/task/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:15 at Function.process_params (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:346:12) at next (/var/task/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:10)`

Please let me know how to change the views folder that vercel is looking for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue also.
In my case the problem was path setting for views folder and for the folders containing static files.
So provide the full path instead of the path in local.

change this

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public")) and all static folders like this
```

to

```
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "public"));
```

Hope this will help you......