# Vercel deployment: what affects files list at runtime?

Tags: vercel

Practically I already solved my problem with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77118829/3400830), but now I'm looking for the explanation.

Official documentation says [that `process.cwd()` is expected way to read files relatively](https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-use-files-in-serverless-functions), but in my express app using `process.cwd()` brings an error, that there is no such file. After some investigation I discovered that files on the fs are different in different cases. The difference in the cases is the only line (it's express application).

I added some debug endpoint to investigate

```js
app.get('/list', (req, res) => {
    let cwdList = glob.sync('**/**', {
        ignore: ['node_modules/**'] 
    });
    let dirList = glob.sync('**/**', {
        cwd: __dirname + '/..',
        ignore: ['node_modules/**'] 
    })
    res.send({ cwdList, dirList, __dirname: path.resolve(__dirname, '..'), cwd: process.cwd(),views: app.get('views') });
})
```

And here are results

1. `app.set('views', process.cwd() + '/public/templates')`  - fails as there is no public directory

```
{
  "cwdList": [
    ".",
    "src",
    "package.json",
    "___vc",
    "src/expressServer.js.map",
    "src/expressServer.js",
    "___vc/__launcher",
    "___vc/__esm_launcher.mjs",
    "___vc/__launcher/web-interop-2GETHLCQ.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/package.json",
    "___vc/__launcher/initialize-n1-23C2KE6A.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/helpers-23SL6TQX.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/edge-config-socket-BIQMTURH.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-T3JRUTQC.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-OAGYRVOD.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-MV3GYRHF.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-K5DCHW46.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-GZGYYLSH.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-FLNFOE7B.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/bridge-server-isolated-WSMXEH6E.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/bridge-server-72TT5FOD.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/__sourcemap_support.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/__helpers.js"
  ],
  "dirList": [
    ".",
    "src",
    "package.json",
    "___vc",
    "src/expressServer.js.map",
    "src/expressServer.js",
    "___vc/__launcher",
    "___vc/__esm_launcher.mjs",
    "___vc/__launcher/web-interop-2GETHLCQ.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/package.json",
    "___vc/__launcher/initialize-n1-23C2KE6A.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/helpers-23SL6TQX.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/edge-config-socket-BIQMTURH.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-T3JRUTQC.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-OAGYRVOD.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-MV3GYRHF.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-K5DCHW46.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-GZGYYLSH.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-FLNFOE7B.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/bridge-server-isolated-WSMXEH6E.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/bridge-server-72TT5FOD.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/__sourcemap_support.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/__helpers.js"
  ],
  "__dirname": "/var/task",
  "cwd": "/var/task",
  "views": "/var/task/public/templates"
}
```

2. `app.set('views', __dirname + '/../public/templates')` - works as public directory is presented

```
{
  "cwdList": [
    ".",
    "src",
    "public",
    "package.json",
    "___vc",
    "src/expressServer.js.map",
    "src/expressServer.js",
    "public/templates",
    "public/templates/message.ejs",
    "___vc/__launcher",
    "___vc/__esm_launcher.mjs",
    "___vc/__launcher/web-interop-2GETHLCQ.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/package.json",
    "___vc/__launcher/initialize-n1-23C2KE6A.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/helpers-23SL6TQX.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/edge-config-socket-BIQMTURH.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-T3JRUTQC.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-OAGYRVOD.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-MV3GYRHF.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-K5DCHW46.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-GZGYYLSH.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-FLNFOE7B.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/bridge-server-isolated-WSMXEH6E.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/bridge-server-72TT5FOD.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/__sourcemap_support.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/__helpers.js"
  ],
  "dirList": [
    ".",
    "src",
    "public",
    "package.json",
    "___vc",
    "src/expressServer.js.map",
    "src/expressServer.js",
    "public/templates",
    "public/templates/message.ejs",
    "___vc/__launcher",
    "___vc/__esm_launcher.mjs",
    "___vc/__launcher/web-interop-2GETHLCQ.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/package.json",
    "___vc/__launcher/initialize-n1-23C2KE6A.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/helpers-23SL6TQX.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/edge-config-socket-BIQMTURH.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-T3JRUTQC.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-OAGYRVOD.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-MV3GYRHF.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-K5DCHW46.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-GZGYYLSH.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/chunk-FLNFOE7B.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/bridge-server-isolated-WSMXEH6E.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/bridge-server-72TT5FOD.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/__sourcemap_support.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/__launcher.js",
    "___vc/__launcher/__helpers.js"
  ],
  "__dirname": "/var/task",
  "cwd": "/var/task",
  "views": "/var/task/src/../public/templates"
}
```

So the question is - why using different ways to define `views` for `express` makes that difference even though it looks like both ways are resolved the the same path

| `app.set('views', __dirname + '/../public/templates')` | `app.set('views', process.cwd() + '/public/templates')` |
| --- | --- |
| `/var/task/src/../public/templates` | `/var/task/public/templates` |